# How to remove Duplicate value from arraylist in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();
values.add("s");
values.add("n");
values.add("a");
values.add("s");
```

In this Array, I want to remove repeated values.

Comment: Why dont you use a [set](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) then ?

Answer (score 84):

Try this...

```
    ArrayList<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();
    HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
    hashSet.addAll(values);
    values.clear();
    values.addAll(hashSet);
```

Comment: All you did was copy the top answer...

Comment: @BrandonLaBraunCurry to be fair, the top answer copied his as well, from another post

Answer (score 36):

Try below code,

```
ArrayList<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();
String newValue;

// repeated additions:
if (!values.contains(newValue)) {values.add(newValue);}
```

Comment: what about custom bean class ? How to solve duplicate value problem ?

Comment: @AnandSavjani override equals() and hash() in your bean, compare by custom field

Comment: This will also maintain order as opposed to hash set +1

Comment: This is the right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

```
HashSet hs = new HashSet();

hs.addAll(demoArrayList); // demoArrayList= name of arrayList from which u want to remove duplicates 

demoArrayList.clear();
demoArrayList.addAll(hs);
```

Comment: Much Much more efficient than ArrayList.contains()

Comment: Notice that the order of the elements added will be unorganized in a HashSet.

Answer (score 2):

I think a real neat solution for enforcing unique array lists is [this one](http://weblog.dangertree.net/2007/06/09/unique-arraylist/), if it's not too much code for what you're trying to achieve.

```
public class UniqueOverridingList extends ArrayList {

    public enum LAST_RESULT {
        ADD, OVERRIDE, NOTHING;
    }

    private LAST_RESULT lastResult;

    public boolean add(T obj) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            if (obj.equals(get(i))) {
                set(i, obj);
                lastResult = LAST_RESULT.OVERRIDE;
                return true;
            }
        }
        boolean b = super.add(obj);
        if (b) {
            lastResult = LAST_RESULT.ADD;
        } else {
            lastResult = LAST_RESULT.NOTHING;
        }
        return b;
    }

    public boolean addAll(Collection c) {
        boolean result = true;
        for (T t : c) {
            if (!add(t)) {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public LAST_RESULT getLastResult() {
        return lastResult;
    }

}
```

Comment: @JohanWikström these need to go through Faq forcefully  before starting here

Answer (score 1):

The class David Hedlund suggested can be made a lot shorter:

```
public class UniqueArrayList extends ArrayList {
    /**
     * Only add the object if there is not
     * another copy of it in the list
     */
    public boolean add(T obj) {
        if(this.contains(obj))
           return false;
        return super.add(obj);
    }

    public boolean addAll(Collection c) {
        boolean result = false;
        for (T t : c) {
            if (add(t)) {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The `addAll` operation is modified too. The [documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28java.lang.Object%29) states:

> Returns: true if this list changed as a result of the call.

I modified the method to reflect this behaviour. There's still one problem. The documentation of the addAll() method also states:

> Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified collection's iterator.

The order might be broken by using this method. A possible workaround for this problem might be not supporting the `addAll` method.

Comment: This makes adding an element O(n).  Use a Set instead!