# Android plot repeated values in the Y axis

Tags: android, plot

I'm using android plot library to plot data from an array I have. The problem is when there are duplicate data in the array , some number labels of the y axis are also being duplicated.
for example if I have an array

> {46.66,46.50,46.61,46.61,46.55,46.55,46.60,46.50,46.50,46.50,46.61,46.41,46.54,46.44,46.46,46.55,46.59,46.61,46.64,46.60,46.65,46.74,46.74,46.99,46.95,46.94,46.80,46.98,46.90,46.94,47.00,46.94,47.11
>   }

I get  46.6 and 47 duplicated on the y-axis.

Sorry I couldn't post an image because of my low reputation.

Comment: Do you need to get the array sorted and duplicate values removed or only duplicate values removed ?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a `Set` for unique values allowing no duplicates:

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets
>   contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at
>   most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models
>   the mathematical set abstraction.

If you decide to stick with `ArrayList` there are many posts about removing duplicates or making extended class to disallow same values added:

[How to remove Duplicate value from arraylist in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879700/how-to-remove-duplicate-value-from-arraylist-in-android)

Comment: i thought of this, but wouldn't that decrease the size of the arraylist and remove values i want to plot, so for example if i have 20 values and 5 duplicates, then i would have 15 values instead of 20 and this is not right for my graph.

Comment: The image of your graph now and image of graph wanted would help a lot in this, can you post images somewhere else and provide links?

Comment: Okay I see, why the graph is not correct if you remove duplicate values?

Comment: because it represents real data, removing a duplicate  is like removing a record that should be included even if it was repeated

Comment: i think it's a bug in this library

Comment: Ah I understand, can't help any further unless you have the library source code and you can modify that to fix the issue.